# Porque python me reconoce la resta acumulativa y no la suma acumulativa?

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con la suma de strings en python.

Tengo el siguiente map que contiene numeros romanos y sus valores:

```
numerosR = {'I':'1', 'V':'5', 'X':'10', 'L':'50', 'C':'100', 'D':'100', 'M':'1000'}
```

En mi funcion le paso una cadena con numeros romanos y debo devolver el numero en si.

Para ello realice lo siguiente:

```
result = 0        
    
    for i in range(len(s)):
        
        if i + 1 < len(s) and numerosR[s[i]] < numerosR[s[i+1]]:
            
            result -= numerosR[s[i]]
            
        else:             
            result += numerosR[s[i]]
        
    return result
```

No se porque el programa me reconoce la linea de la resta acumulativa

```
result -= numerosR[s[i]]
```

Pero no el de la suma acumulativa:

```
result += numerosR[s[i]]
```

El error que me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
result += numerosR[s[i]]
```

Porque sucede esto? Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Cómo es eso de que te reconoce la resta? No puede ser, ha de darte el mismo error que la suma. Probablemente es que la condición del `if` era falsa y no entró por esa rama.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

En python el operador `+` se utiliza para sumar enteros y para concatenar texto, es por eso que cuando intentas utilizarlo con una combinación de enteros y string te arroja ese error.

Sumando enteros: `x = 1 + 2` devuelve `x=3`

Concatenando texto: `x = 'Concatenar ' + 'texto'` devuelve `x = 'Concatenar texto'`

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar sólo enteros en la definición de numerosR

`numerosR = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':100, 'M':1000}`

Porque en tu código los declaras como string (Los declaras entre comillas)

`numerosR = {'I':'1', 'V':'5', 'X':'10', 'L':'50', 'C':'100', 'D':'100', 'M':'1000'}`

Es por eso que sale el error